# Palavras com acento não funcionam

Tags: php, html, ajax

Tenho Ajax que carrega dados do banco e no tipo json:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '../model/dao/CursoDao.php?acao=1',
    success: function(dados){

        for(var i=0; dados.length > i; i++){

            $('#listaCursos').append('<a href="sala_view.php?idcurso='+ dados[i].id + '" class="btn btn-primary texto-grande botao-nivel sombra">' + dados[i].titulo +'</a>');

        }
    }
});
```

A função do PHP:

```
  public function listaCursoAjax() {

$sqlCurso = $this->conexao->prepare('SELECT * FROM curso');
$sqlCurso->execute();

while($linha = $sqlCurso->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $vetor[] = array_map('utf8_encode',$linha);
}

echo json_encode($vetor);
```

}

O problema é que as frases com acento estão vindo codificadas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente codificar pra base64 e decodificar na saída, os acentos devem se manter como eram :)

Comment: @WesleyNascimento quando passo assim array_map('base64_encode',$linha);
ficar pior ainda

Comment: Vou te responder como deve ser, está fazendo errado.

Comment: Veja o que eu editei e me de um retorno, se funcionou ou não...

Comment: Com cadeira será que funciona?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente utilizar o seguinte código:

```
    public function listaCursoAjax() {

    $sqlCurso = $this->conexao->prepare('SELECT * FROM curso');
    $sqlCurso->execute();

    while($linha = $sqlCurso->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        foreach($linha as &$result){
            $result = utf8_encode($result);
        }
        $vetor[] = $linha;
    }


echo json_encode($vetor);
```

Comment: Continua com a página em branco Wesley

Comment: Estou sem apache, portanto, não tenho como testar o código que eu te falo, ta difícil :/ mas a lógica é essa cara, percorrer todo o objeto $linha e codificar tudo nele antes de enviar.

Comment: Editei, de novo, teste por favor e me fala se funcionou. Se retornar a página em branco tente substituir o $vetor[] = $linha; por um echo qualquer pra testar...

Comment: Continua em Branco e ta dando esses erros: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\vocacaosaude\model\dao\CursoDao.php on line 77
Array
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\vocacaosaude\model\dao\CursoDao.php on line 77
Array
Notice: Undefined variable: vetor in C:\xampp\htdocs\vocacaosaude\model\dao\CursoDao.php on line 81
null

Comment: Retire a linha $vetor[] = $linha; e acrescente, no mesmo lugar, um echo "teste";, poste resultados

Comment: Nossa, quando eu editei o código eu manti uma parte do código anterior, erro meu, teste de novo, por favor.

Comment: Ele mostra, mas continua que na imagem que eu postei, com nome condificado, quando acesso o arquivo ele ta retornando o json de boa:

[{"id":"6","titulo":"Curso - Eu Atleta 1"},{"id":"7","titulo":"Curso - Eu Atleta 2"},{"id":"8","titulo":"Malha\u00c3\u00a7\u00c3\u00a3o"}]

Comment: Então o problema não é na criação do json, tenta colocar isso no ajax:
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-15",

Comment: beleza vou tentar